# How to find which Canvas item is closer to the point clicked in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to find which `Canvas` item is closer to the point I clicked. I am trying to use find the closest but I can't use it efficiently. I am trying to make an `itemlist` and then find which item is the closest in the `itemlist`. I also have `self` keywords since I'm trying to do all this using classes

```
def initUI(self):
    self.canvas = Canvas(self.parent)
    self.item1 = self.canvas.create_oval(50, 50, 60, 60, fill="red")
    self.item2 = self.canvas.create_oval(100, 100, 110, 110, fill="red")
    self.item3 = self.canvas.create_oval(150, 150, 160, 160, fill="red")
    self.itemlist = []
    self.itemlist.append(self.item1)
    self.itemlist.append(self.item2)
    self.itemlist.append(self.item3)
    print(self.itemlist) 
    self.canvas.pack()
    self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.find_closest)

def find_closest(self, event):
""" """
```

Comment: Are you aware that the canvas has a documented method named `find_closest`?

Comment: Here's a little [documentation](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/canvas-methods.html) on the `Canvas` widget's own `find_closest()` method.

Comment: Besides that, note that `Canvas` widget's also have a `find_all()` method which will return a list of all the objects currently on the canvas — so you generally would never need to create and maintain your own list of them.

Comment: I was aware I should use find_closest but I couldnt use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments you can use the Canvas method `find_closest()` to do what's needed. Below is a runnable example of doing that based on the code in your question. It uses an auxilary dictionary to map the ids of the canvas object to arbitrary strings (referred to as "names" in the example).

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import *

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.parent)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.find_closest)

       # Create dictionary mapping canvas object ids to a name.
        self.object_names = {}
        id = self.canvas.create_oval(50, 50, 60, 60, fill="Red")
        self.object_names[id] = 'Red object'
        id = self.canvas.create_oval(100, 100, 110, 110, fill="Blue")
        self.object_names[id] = 'Blue object'
        id = self.canvas.create_oval(150, 150, 160, 160, fill="Green")
        self.object_names[id] = 'Green object'

        self.name_lbl1 = tk.Label(self.parent, text='Closest object:')
        self.name_lbl1.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.name_var = tk.StringVar(value='')
        self.name_lbl2 = tk.Label(self.parent, textvariable=self.name_var)
        self.name_lbl2.pack(side=LEFT)

    def find_closest(self, event):
        if (closest := self.canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)):
            obj_id = closest[0]
            self.name_var.set(self.object_names[obj_id])  # Updates lbl2.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    instance = MyClass(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot of it running:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I knew I should use it, but I couldn't figure out how to use it. I will try this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: zorlubedo: I thought that might be the case…and decided to provide you with an working example. The fact that  the `Canvas.find_closest()` method returns a singleton tuple was kind of a weird interface decision IMO.